Vertically and horizontally centered wrapped text in cell
This is, I'm sure, just me being stupid...
It need not be a cell. I am just after square boxes of fixed dimensions, with every alternate row's text inverted, and wrapped. Text will not overfill the box.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 

\begin{document} 

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
 >{\vbox to 2.5cm\bgroup\vfill\centering\arraybackslash}%
 p{#1}%
 <{\vskip-\baselineskip\vfill\egroup}}  

 \begin{tabular}{| C{2.5cm} | C{2.5cm} | C{2.5cm}  |}
   \hline 
   Axxxx  & Bxxxx & Cxxxx \\ \hline
   \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{Ayyyy plus a small amount of text}}  & \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{Byyyy plus a small amount of text}} & \raisebox{\depth}{\scalebox{-1}[-1]{Cyyyy plus a small amount of text}} \\ \hline    
 \end{tabular}   
  
\end{document}

For the interested, these are for labels to go with items in a museum collection.

You could use the tabularray package:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{tabularray}
\newcommand{\rotation}[1]{\rotatebox{180}{\parbox{2.5cm}{\centering #1}}}

\begin{document} 

 \begin{tblr}{
  vlines, hlines,
  columns = {wd=2.5cm,valign=m},
  rows = {ht=2.5cm,halign=c},
  row{even} = {cmd=\rotation},
 }
   Axxxx  & Bxxxx & Cxxxx \\ 
  Ayyyy plus a small amount of text  & Byyyy plus a small amount of text & Cyyyy plus a small amount of text\\    
 \end{tblr}   
  
\end{document}



Thanks very much, really helpful

@alice19 You're welcome!
